# SQL Retrieve rows that have all rows from other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I am facing some issues retrieving data using SQL in one specific scenario:

Suppose I have the following tables:

- `A` (id, attr_a, attr_b);
- `B` (id, attr_d, attr_e);
- `C` (id_a, id_b);

As you can see, table `C` have `FK` referencing id from table `A`, and referencing id from table `C`.

I need to retrieve table `A` rows that for each `A` row relates to every `B` row.

In a real life scenario, assuming `A` means users, `B` means privileges, and `C` is the many to many entity that relates users with privileges, I would want to get only users that have ALL privileges

Comment: use inner join on a and b?

Comment: @user1490835 a and b dont have a relationship so I cannot use inner join, also, I want only A rows, that have all B id`s, so join would not work, it needs to be more restrict

Comment: `a and b dont have a relationship` ... yes they do, through table `C`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen of course.

Answer (score 2):

```
select A.*
from A
join C on id_a = id
group by id
having count(id) = (select count(*) from B)
```

There is no need to use a subquery because `A.id` is a primary key (or unique at least) as a column referenced by `C.id_a`.

Answer (score 1):

The following query should return all `A` records where, for a given ID, they match to every record in the `B` table.  Note that a subquery is necessary if you want to return every full record in `A`.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM A t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT A.id
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN C
        ON A.id = C.id_a
    GROUP BY A.id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B)
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming referential integrity enforced by FK constraints, all key columns `NOT NULL` and a UNIQUE or PK constraint on `(id_a, id_b)` in `C`.

If all you need is IDs, only work with table `C`. Don't waste time joining to `A`:

```
SELECT id_a
FROM   C
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING count(*) = (SELECT count(*) FROM B);
```

If you need columns or whole rows from `A`, join to it *after* aggregating and eliminating non-qualifying rows. Should be fastest.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM  (
   SELECT id_a AS id
   FROM   C
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING count(*) = (SELECT count(*) FROM B)
   ) c
JOIN   A USING (id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you really only need table C if what you want is a list of users that have every privilege. One way to this is with `CONCAT` which looks at the pairing between `C.id_a` and `C.id_b` as one string:

```
SELECT C.id_a
 FROM C
 GROUP BY C.id_a
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(C.id_a, C.id_b)) =
 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C.id_b)
  FROM C)
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f92a54/3

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to count, you only need to check for (non)existant rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM B
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM C
                WHERE C.id_a = A.id AND C.id_b = B.id
                )
        );
```